# Adding baggage allownce

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, india

I’m going to travel to india from Australia. As I’m going to add 5 kg extra baggage allowance. Somebody told me if i add extra allowance then the custom at Delhi Airport gonna do checking and i may have to open my bag. Is that true?

Comment: It’s always possible that Customs will ask to inspect your luggage, no matter where you’re travelling from/to or how much luggage you have. Travelling with a large amount of baggage may attract more attention, as may travelling alone. How much baggage will you have in total? What is your citizenship? Duty free allowances vary depending on your personal circumstances https://www.immihelp.com/travel-to-india/baggage-allowance-rules/

Comment: Customs in Delhi is well after luggage pickup. They have no way to know how much your luggage weighs (unless the baggage cart breaks down from it).

Comment: In total i have 34kg luggage and I’m india citizen. Do u think so i have to take out the things or I’ll be fine? I’m so scared now

Comment: @Neha sharma You haven’t said what kind of ‘things’ will be in your luggage. AFAIK, it’s contents that matter when it comes to paying any duty, not weight. Used personal effects are generally ok, for example, but jewellery, laptops etc may need to be declared depending on the value.

Comment: It’s just makeup, clothes and ps4 for my brother.

Comment: Note that you are generally not allowed to have a single bad weighing over 32kg, even if you pay extra. You would need to split your stuff in 2 or more bags.

Comment: Also, anything you bought abroad and intend to leave in India should be declared and you might have to pay import taxes and duties on it, unless the total remains under your duty-free allowances.

Answer (score 1):

Very unlikely.

Weight of your baggage is between you and the airline. Customs has no way of knowing what the weight of your luggage is so they can't use weight as an indicator for extra scrutiny.

Sometimes the airlines will put a sticker stating "Heavy" or similar on your bag so that the baggage handler can follow proper protocol for overweight luggage. If you are worried about that, you can simply remove any stickers after you have collected your bags from the belt and before you take them through customs